# AttributeRouting - Method to get routes in assembly

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, attributerouting

I want to use [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) with Orchard CMS. To do so I need to implement an `IRouteProvider` with a method that returns an list of Orchard `RouteDescriptor`s.

I need a way to get the routes list so I can do something like this:

```
   public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return _routes ?? (_routes = MvcRouting.GetRoutes(GetType().Assembly).Select(route => new RouteDescriptor
        {
            ...
        }).ToArray());
    }
```

This method is from MvcRouting but I want to use the more feature rich [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) but cannot find a way to scan current assembly for routing attributes. Need a way for AttributeRouting to return the list of routes that I can project into a list of `RouteDescriptor`s but not actually registering them, leaving that to Orchard.

```
 public class RouteDescriptor {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public System.Web.Routing.RouteBase Route { get; set; }
    public System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior SessionState { get; set; }
}
```

If I wanted to register the routes directly (in a non-Orchard project) I would use the following AttributeRouting extension methods:

```
  routesCollection.MapAttributeRoutes(config =>
        {
            config.AddRoutesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
```

But this won't place nice with other Orchard modules. So need to take the approach above.

Any way you can think of?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Routes are common resources, and modules need to play nice with each other. You need to use the routing APIs that Orchard provides.

Comment: I vaguely remember moving some projects into Orchard and having problems since if you use Multi-Tenancy routes cannot have names. As Bertrand said, just use Orchards routing

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Well, there is this project that I got the idea from https://github.com/benjaminkeeping/Orchard.Routing I don't see why I can't define my routes using attributes and still have it play nice with other modules. Not like I want to register them myself, I just want to get a list of the route attributes that decorate my controllers in this particular module and pass it to Orchard to actually register them. Why wouldn't this work by design?

Comment: @Hazza I have built a multi-tenant non-Orchard application using subdomain routing feature in AttributeRouting. For this case I don't need multi-tenancy but that might be an option using subdomain routing http://attributerouting.net/#subdomains

Comment: Just asking. I don't like to put routes on controllers myself but if that's what you want to do... Not sure what problem you're seeing however. Looks like it's simple reflection. When you say "this won't play nice", how so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bertrand already noted, what you need is a simple reflection over currently available `Controller` types.

1. Implement `IRouteProvider` as you already did.
2. Grab all `Controller` types exported by currently enabled modules

   ```
   IExtensionManager _extensions;
   ShellBlueprint _shell;
   ...
   var types = _extensions
                   .LoadFeatures(_extensions.EnabledFeatures(_shell.Descriptor))
                       .SelectMany(feature => feature
                           .ExportedTypes
                           .Where(t => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(t)));
   ```
3. Loop over methods of each of the types above and pick those that have a given attribute defined. For each of the methods picked, fetch its name (action name), name of the assembly that contains its declaring type (area name) along with the attribute data (route pattern etc.).
4. Having the collection above in hand, you can simply loop over it and return `new RouteDescriptor{ ... }` for each.